# Find the value of $3^9\cdot 3^3\cdot 3\cdot 3^{1/3}\cdot\cdots$

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, infinite-product

> Find the value of $3^9\cdot 3^3\cdot 3\cdot 3^{1/3}\cdot\cdots$

Doesn't this thing approaches 0 at the end?  why does it approaches 1?

Comment: would you mind to write out the product series in a formula?

Comment: sorry i couldnt post the question on my account due to the stupid 24 hour limit

Comment: The last factor in the product, $3^{3^{-n}}$ doesn't go to 0, it approaches 1.

Comment: How could it possibly be zero, given that each term is bigger than $1$?

Answer (score 27):

Hint:  $3^9\cdot3^3\cdot3^1\cdot\dots=3^{9+3+1+\cdots}$

Answer (score 15):

HINT:

Using [Exponent Combination Laws](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws),
$$a^m\cdot a^n\cdot a^p\cdots=a^{m+n+p+\cdot},$$

$$\displaystyle 3^9\cdot 3^3\cdot3\cdot 3^\frac13\cdots=3^{\left(3^2+3+1+\frac13+\cdots\right)}$$

Observe that the power of $3$ is an [infinite](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Geometric_sequence#Infinite_Geometric_Sequences) Geometric Series with the first Term $=9$ and common ratio $=\frac13<1$

Answer (score 11):

$$3^9 * 3^3 * 3 * 3^{\frac{1}{3}} * ...=$$

$$3^{9\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^{-n}}=$$
$$3^{9*1.5}=$$
$$3^{13.5}$$

Answer (score 9):

$ 3^{12} \times 3^{sum\ of\ geometric\ series }$

geometric series is

$ 1 + 1/3 + 1/9 + .... $

$ = 1 / (1-1/3) $

$ = 3/2 $

so

$= 3^ {12 + \frac{3}{2} } $

$= 3 ^{ 27/2 } $